# How to Analyze Data with two independent categorical variables

Tags: logistic, categorical-data

How would you see if a difference is significant in a summary table with two independent categorical variables. Say I have Green Dogs, Red Dogs, Green Cats, and Red Cats and I have data about how many in each group ate within the last 4 hours. How do I know if being Green or Red is statistically significant? Being a Cat vs. being a Dog?

For example:

Green Dogs 77/93
Red Dogs 66/82
Green Cats 64/84
Red Cats 31/34

Comment: You formulate it as a 2x2 contingency table and apply a chi square or Fisher's exact test.

Comment: Thanks Michael for your response. Does that still work if there are two independent variables and a dependent variable. It seems like I need a 3D table, i.e. 2x2x2. Can I do a Chi square on that?